# TTNavigation and storyboards

Tags: ios, three20, uistoryboard

Is it possible to use TTNavigation while using storyboards? If so can someone help point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no interface builder support at all in three20 whatsoever.

All your view controllers and views have to be created programmatically